# plsql using in datagrip ide

Tags: oracle, plsql, datagrip

When I am running PL/SQL scripts in Datagrip I am getting task compiled but I cannot see the output how to get an output in datagrip,
and when I am running dynamic block it's not taking input value in datagrip.

```
declare
    v1 emp.empno%type := '&empno';
    v2 emp.ename%type;
begin
    select empno,ename into v1,v2 from emp where empno = v1;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v1 || ' ' || v2);
end;
```

it shows this error

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error

Does anyone have any solution?

Answer (score 4):

**Enable DBMS_OUTPUT** button is placed on the right toolbar of the *Services* window

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't use DataGrip.

---

Looks like you should **enable** dbms_output. How? Try with [Ctrl + F8] (as a keyboard shortcut), or push the appropriate button (tooltip says "Enable SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT").

---

As of the second part of your question, [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/settings-tools-database-user-parameters.html) says

> Generally, only the question mark ? is treated as a parameter in SQL statements, which means that you might need to do this:

```
v1 emp.empno%type := ?;
```

Because, code you posted works OK in e.g. SQL Developer or SQL*Plus:

Enabling DBMS_OUTPUT:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
```

Code execution:

```
SQL> declare
  2      v1 emp.empno%type := '&empno';
  3      v2 emp.ename%type;
  4  begin
  5      select empno,ename into v1,v2 from emp where empno = v1;
  6      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v1 || ' ' || v2);
  7  end;
  8  /
Enter value for empno: 7369
7369 SMITH                                 --> this is the result

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Finally, ORA-06502: it happens when you pass something that isn't a number (while number is expected); for example, I'll pass `ABC`:

```
SQL> /
Enter value for empno: ABC
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at line 2


SQL>
```

See? The same error you got. **Maybe** it all has to do something with improper usage of a substitution variable, i.e. `'&empno'` vs. `?`